# peer to peer connect behind router? each peer can not accept incoming connections. They can make outgoing connection

Tags: python, nat

Client A is behind the Router and can not accept the incoming connection.
Client B is behind the Router and can not accept the incoming connection.

I have server S which can accept the connection but only share the information about IP address and Port of different client.

Now how can I connect Client A and Client B directly with out sending message to server S i.e peer to peer connection?

I was using socket python program but can not established direct connection between client A and Client B. I do not want any message to be pass via Server S.

Answer (score 0):

I found this project which implements the WebRTC standard in python. I think it's what you're looking for: https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc

Why WebRTC for p2p?

On a standard router with standard NAT settings p2p connections are not possible by default. NAT is designed this way to stop rogue machines from connecting to you without your permission. But there are a few methods to connect p2p through NAT.

One is "Port forwarding". You can manually "open" ports in a router. Programs such as torrent clients use "uPnP" to temporarily ask for ports to be "opened", but only if uPnP is enabled in the router settings. So Port forwarding is dependent on special router settings, so it's not ideal.

Another is "hole punching". A STUN server is used as an intermediary to initiate a connection between 2 peers. After the connection is established the STUN server does not relay traffic, the 2 peers communicate directly.

The beauty of hole punching using a simple STUN server is that it doesn't break the fundamental design of NAT that I mentioned above. Because both clients must connect to the same STUN server (usually at roughly the same time) it means both peers are genuinely trying to connect to each other, thus it's most likely not an attack / rogue machine.

Also there are plenty of free STUN servers available (as it's not expensive to keep them running because they don't actually relay traffic). The downside of hole punching is that it usually only works with UDP, not TCP.

In web browsers the WebRTC standard came along some years ago to standardize the hole punch technique (UDP) and provide an API for browsers to easily implement it. Allowing video and audio p2p streams between web browsers directly with just a little help from any simple STUN server.

It's important to note hole punching will not work in some rare cases depending on the NAT setting of the connecting routers. This chart lists the combinations:

[image: This chart lists the combinations:]